# BSD license compliance with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, uglifyjs

React is distributed under BSD style license. How to satisfy this requirement when I minify resulting JS file? I.e. many libraries have licensing headers which include special metadata but not React.

I use webpack with uglifyjs for minification. Uglifyjs has an option to preserve comments but it includes everything. There's also a plugin for uglify but I wasn't able to integrate it with webpack.

Comment: That is off-topic here, but I like the question very much. Ask it over at opensource.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's not a question for opensource.stackexchange.com. We need to comply with the license, no questions asked. The question is how to implement it with webpack.

Comment: other than that, BSD licenses are pretty clear: the license statement must stay part of the distributed code or binary. you might under no circumstances "optimize" it away. That's why cloudflare & co are in constant violation.

Comment: so manually remove all comments but the license comment? Or remove all comment and add the license comment back in afterwards? You could also convert the comment to a string.

Comment: @MarcusMüller One workaround is to manually add /*! at the headers in node_modules but it's brittle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an answer myself. I used this project for it https://github.com/shinnn/uglify-save-license

Just add the following to webpack.config.js:

```
  const saveLicense = require('uglify-save-license');

  ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      output: {
        comments: saveLicense
      }
    }),
    ...
 ]
```

Copyright headers are included many times, but it's not that a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

You now won't have that issue as React 16 is to be licensed under an MIT license. https://code.facebook.com/posts/300798627056246/relicensing-react-jest-flow-and-immutable-js/